# Is every $A \in \mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb C)$ a product of four unipotent matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Is every matrix $A \in \mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb C)$ a product of four unipotent matrices?

I have verified that this is true if $n = 2$, and I believe I have came across this result before. However, I cannot find a reference to this.

Comment: As a follow-up, is it clear that $4$ is best possible?

Comment: I  suspect it to be in the form $L_1U_1L_2U_2$ where $L$ are lower triangular and $U$ is upper triangular. But perhaps if just unipotent, 4 is not necessary.

Comment: It's easy to check for every field $K$ that every matrix in $\mathrm{SL}_2(K)$ is product of 2 unipotents except precisely $-I_2$: if not upper triangular, multiply on the right by $e_{12}(s)$ for suitable $s$, and similarly if not lower triangular. If diagonal not scalar, multiply on the right by the unipotent $\begin{pmatrix} 1+s &-s^2\\ 1&1-s\end{pmatrix}$ for suitable $s$. In each case, just arrange that the trace of the product is 2, to ensure the product is unipotent. (Hence every matrix in $\mathrm{SL}_2(K)$ is product of 3 unipotents.)

Comment: The optimistic generalization would be that every non-scalar matrix in $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$ is product of 2 unipotents. I've checked it for $n=3$ when $K$ is algebraically closed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In response to Qiaochu's question in the comments, Fong and Sourour prove in their paper [The group generated by unipotent operators](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-097-03/S0002-9939-1986-0840628-0/) that every element of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb C)$ is a product of three unipotent matrices.

Edit: Sourour proves in the paper [A factorization theorem for matrices](https://dspace.library.uvic.ca/handle/1828/1594) that a nonscalar matrix in $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb C)$ is indeed a product of two unipotent matrices, confirming YCor's generalization.

Answer (score 11):

If you only need four factors then you can have much more than that. Namely, you can take as the unipotent matrices upper and lower uni-triangular matrices. It was noted by G. Strang in "[Every unit matrix is a *LULU*](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(96)00598-8)" that for any field $K$ anfy $A\in M(n,K)$ can be presented as $A=U_1L_1U_2L_2$, where $U_i$ are upper uni-triangular and $L_i$ are lower uni-triangular.

In fact, this is true not only for fields, but also for rings of stable rank $1$ (in particular, for semilocal rings, for boolean rings, for the ring of all entire functions and for the ring of algebraic integers), see [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10958-012-0826-z) (the result was known to the experts long before that, but mostly in terms of triangular decompositions).

As noted in the answer by Gjergji Zaimi, there is a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1080/03081088608817711) by A. Sourour, where he proved that over a field $F$ there is a presentation as a product of three unipotent matrices (two for non-central elements). This can not be carried to the decompositions in terms of lower and upper uni-tringular marices. Namely, every matrix $A\in \operatorname{SL}(n, R)$ is a product $U_1LU_2$ if and only if $R$ is a boolean ring ([reference](https://dx.doi.org/10.22108/ijgt.2012.467)). However, T. Toffoli [proved](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(96)00240-6) that almost all (w.r.t. Lebesgue measure) elements of $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ are *ULU*, and that for any $A$ there exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that either $PA$ or $-PA$ is *ULU*.

Answer (score 10):

I have not seen this result before, but here is a proof. Let $e_{ij}$ be the matrix with a $1$ in position $(i,j)$ and all other entries $0$. Let $x_i(t)$ and $y_i(t)$ be the Chevalley generators $\mathrm{Id} + t e_{i (i+1)}$ and $\mathrm{Id} + t e_{(i+1) i}$.

Since being unipotent is unchanged by conjugacy, and every matrix in $\mathrm{SL}_n$ is conjugate to an upper triangular matrix, we may assume that our matrix is upper triangular. So let $A$ be an upper triangular matrix with determinant $1$.

We can choose constants $t_1$, $t_2$, ..., $t_n$ such that $B:= A x_1(t_1) x_2(t_2) \cdots x_{n-1}(t_{n-1})$ has $B_{12} = B_{23} = \cdots = B_{(n-1)n}=1$.

We can then inductively choose $u_1$, $u_2$, ..., $u_{n-1}$ such that the upper left $k \times k$ minor of $C:=B y_1(u_1) y_2(u_2) \cdots y_{n-1}(u_{n-1})$ is $1$. Namely, we choose $u_k$ to make the $k \times k$ minor of $B y_1(u_1) y_2(u_2) \cdots y_k(u_k)$ correct; the later factors won't effect this minor. Since our original matrix is in $\mathrm{SL}_n$, the $n \times n$ minor will also be $1$.

Now, since the upper left minors of $C$ are $1$, the matrix $C$ has an $LU$ factorization where $L$ is lower triangular unipotent and $U$ is upper triangular unipotent. Thus, we have written
$$A = L*U* \left( y_{n-1}(-u_{n-1}) \cdots y_2(-u_2) y_1(-u_1) \right)* \left( x_{n-1}(-t_{n-1}) \cdots x_2(-t_2) x_1(-t_1) \right).$$
This is a product of $4$ unipotent factors.

There was a lot of slack in this argument! I wouldn't be surprised if you could prove something much better, either in the direction of non-algebraically closed fields, or in the direction of a more limited class of factors, but this is what you asked for.